# Windows command line: How to append a variable in a loop?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to fill a variable with a space-separated list of files, but I can't quite seem to get my head around it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
set js_files=
for %%f in (js/*.js) do set js_files=%js_files% js/%%f
echo %js_files%
C:\path\to\jsminifier.exe --inputfiles %js_files%
```

I would have expected this to keep appending the `js_files` variable with the next filename, but instead it replaces the whole variable:

```
c:\dir>script.cmd
c:\dir>set js_files=
c:\dir>for %f in (js/*.js) do set js_files= js/%f
c:\dir>set js_files= js/one.js
c:\dir>set js_files= js/two.js
c:\dir>set js_files= js/three.js
c:\dir>echo  js/three.js
js/three.js
```

I see in the second line of output that the whole `for` line seems to be parsed before execution, so the (initial) empty variable value is used for all iterations.

Does anyone know how to properly append to the variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
set js_files=
for %%f in (js/*.js) do set js_files=!js_files! js/%%f
echo %js_files%
C:\path\to\jsminifier.exe --inputfiles %js_files%
```

Note the change of `set js_files=%js_files% js/%%f` to `set js_files=!js_files! js/%%f` – by using the exclamation points in place of percent signs, you're instructing the shell to expand the environment variable dynamically during execution.

Comment: @Randolf - not really working ... on which `Windows` version does it work for you?

Comment: @RonK:  I used this technique on Windows 7 (64-bit Edition) for some other project a few months ago.

Comment: @RonK:  Oh, I see what's missing -- you'll need to start Cmd with the /V:ON command-line switch first.  Once you do this, then run the batch file, the "delayed environment" feature will work.

Comment: @RonK:  Instead of using the /V:ON switch, just insert this line (two words) at the beginning of your batch file (it will be a lot easier):  `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: Adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and changing to exclamation marks worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan:  +1 for indicating that both items were needed to make it work.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: On some reason the accumulation `set js_files=!js_files! js/%%f` does not work for me whatever I tried (`cmd /v:on` or `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`): the variable `!js_files!` was left unsubstituted. The solution is to call a function and in the function do the accumulation: `for /f %%a in ... do call :expand %%a` and then `:expand` plus `set args=%args% %1` plus `exit /b`